# How can I change this script to skip views?

Tags: oracle, plsql

These statements list all of the columns that contain a certain.  Is is also searching views and I need to know how to skip views.

```
DECLARE
      match_count integer;
      v_search_string varchar2(4000) := 'FE/Operational';

    BEGIN  
      FOR t IN (SELECT owner,
                       table_name, 
                       column_name 
                  FROM all_tab_columns
                 WHERE data_type in ('VARCHAR2','VARCHAR','NCHAR','NVARCHAR2') )

      LOOP   
        BEGIN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE    
            'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||t.owner || '.' || t.table_name||
            ' WHERE '||t.column_name||' = :1'   
             INTO match_count  
            USING v_search_string; 
          IF match_count > 0 THEN 
            dbms_output.put_line( t.owner || '.' || t.table_name ||'
    '||t.column_name||' '||match_count );
          END IF; 
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN others THEN
            dbms_output.put_line( 'Error encountered trying to read ' ||
                                  t.column_name || ' from ' || 
                                  t.owner || '.' || t.table_name );
            dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
        END;
      END LOOP;
    END;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join your query on `all_objects` and check that the object type is a table:

```sql
SELECT owner,
       table_name, 
       column_name 
FROM   all_tab_columns atc
JOIN   all_object ao ON atc.table_name = ao.object_name AND
                        atc.owner = ao.owner
WHERE  data_type IN ('VARCHAR2', 'VARCHAR', 'NCHAR', 'NVARCHAR2') AND
       object_type = 'TABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ALL_OBJECT` view for including only Tables as follows:

```
SELECT
    ATT.OWNER,
    ATT.TABLE_NAME,
    ATT.COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    ALL_TAB_COLUMNS ATT JOIN ALL_OBJECTS AO
    ON ATT.TABLE_NAME = AO.OBJECT_NAME AND ATT.OWNER = AO.OWNER
WHERE
    DATA_TYPE IN (
        'VARCHAR2',
        'VARCHAR',
        'NCHAR',
        'NVARCHAR2'
    )
    AND AO.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
```